# CSS adjust button width to text

Tags: css

I have a problem in my button width. my form is able to switch language. For some language the content of the button is longer then the button width, How can I adjust the button width proprety to the text lenght ?
Here is my CSS :

```
html .formRowSubmit input[type="submit"] { 
  width: 26%;
  margin: 5px 0% 5px ;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: 0;
  -moz-outline-style: none;
  background: #CAD722;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 150;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
}
```

Comment: use html .formRowSubmit input[type="submit"] { width: auto}

Comment: Thank you, It works ! I adjusted also the padding with   padding: 0 10px 0 10px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try setting a `min-width` instead of a width, this will let the button expand if need be. Once you do this you should also set some horizontal padding so the text isnt butted up to the end like so:

```
input[type="submit"] { 
  min-width: 26%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jqjxd0xt/

Comment: This is the best solution. because I ONLY need to adjust when the text is longer. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Display the button as an inline-block (and delete the width)

```
html .formRowSubmit input[type="submit"] { 
  /*width: 26%;*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0% 5px ;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: 0;
  -moz-outline-style: none;
  background: #CAD722;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 150;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
}
```

You might want to add some padding if the text is to close to the border.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this: **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j6Lgdhxe/)**

CSS:

```
.formRowSubmit input[type="submit"] {
    width: auto;
    margin: 5px 0% 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-outline-style: none;
    background: #CAD722;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 150;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="formRowSubmit">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit loooong llloooonnnng text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.  but you padded vertically not horizontally ;) you should   padding: 0 5px 0 5px;